# Create a new array with unique files from duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, object, duplicates

My goal here is to create an array of unique files (no duplicates), and return that array. I seem to be having trouble determining the correct size of unique, unduplicated values. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public static File[] getUniqueSet(File[] files)
    {

        // Find size of unique File objects array

        int uniqueFileAmt = files.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < files.length; j++)
            {
                if (i != j && (files[i].equals(files[j])))
                    uniqueFileAmt--;
            }
        }

        File[] uniqueFiles = new File[uniqueFileAmt + 1];
        int uniquePos = 0;

        // Add unique files to array uniqueFiles, avoiding duplicates

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < files.length; j++)
            {
                if (i != j && (! files[i].equals(files[j])))
                {
                    uniqueFiles[uniquePos] = files[j];
                    uniquePos++;
                }
            }
        }

        return uniqueFiles;
    }
```

Comment: **JAVASCRIPT != JAVA**!

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at `uniqueFileAmt--`. This is executed too often if the same file exists more than two times in the array. Let's say it's present at indexes 0, 2 and 3. It is executed when...

- i = 0 and j = 2
- i = 0 and j = 3
- i = 2 and j = 3

There is a general problem with your logic. When you look at your second part, building the new array, `file[0]` would never be added, even if unique. On the other hand the code is adding pretty much everything, most of the time multiple times, as far as there is one file before the current file which it is distinct from.

Think again about the problem and try to find a different solution. If this is not to be done for some homework I'd suggest you to move away from plain arrays and make yourself familiar with the [Collection classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Set** is exclusively unique items.

```
    File[] files= f.listFiles();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(files));
    Set<File> setFiles = new HashSet<File>(Arrays.asList(files));
    File[] uniqueFiles = setFiles.toArray(new File[setFiles.size()]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(uniqueFiles));
```

That's why it's HashSet order will be different